# Как циклом перебрать промежуток времени в днях и узнать дни недели?

Tags: python, python-3.x, дата, datetime

```py
import datetime 
d1 = datetime.date(2020, 3, 1)
d2 = datetime.date(2020, 3, 30)
d3 = d2 - d1 # 29 days
```

Как проитерироваться по `d3`, например, чтобы можно было узнать какой это день недели?

Чтобы получилось что-то типо такого, но работающего:

```py
for i in d3:
    if d3[i] == d3[i].weekday:
        print(+)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [42]: for i in range(d3.days):
    ...:     dt = d1 + datetime.timedelta(i)
    ...:     print(f"{dt}\t-->\tweekday:\t{dt.weekday()}")
    ...:
2020-03-01      -->     weekday:        6
2020-03-02      -->     weekday:        0
2020-03-03      -->     weekday:        1
2020-03-04      -->     weekday:        2
2020-03-05      -->     weekday:        3
2020-03-06      -->     weekday:        4
2020-03-07      -->     weekday:        5
2020-03-08      -->     weekday:        6
2020-03-09      -->     weekday:        0
2020-03-10      -->     weekday:        1
2020-03-11      -->     weekday:        2
2020-03-12      -->     weekday:        3
2020-03-13      -->     weekday:        4
2020-03-14      -->     weekday:        5
2020-03-15      -->     weekday:        6
2020-03-16      -->     weekday:        0
2020-03-17      -->     weekday:        1
2020-03-18      -->     weekday:        2
2020-03-19      -->     weekday:        3
2020-03-20      -->     weekday:        4
2020-03-21      -->     weekday:        5
2020-03-22      -->     weekday:        6
2020-03-23      -->     weekday:        0
2020-03-24      -->     weekday:        1
2020-03-25      -->     weekday:        2
2020-03-26      -->     weekday:        3
2020-03-27      -->     weekday:        4
2020-03-28      -->     weekday:        5
2020-03-29      -->     weekday:        6
```